# How to view definition of existing GA4 custom events

Tags: google-analytics-4, custom-events

**The problem I am having:**
In GA4 I am able to see the list of custom events (in Admin). Here is an example of a few:
[image]

I cannot seem to figure out how to view how these events were defined.

The reason this is important is that the report seen when clicking directly on a custom event from the admin screen isn't showing any helpful information related to the event. My assumption is that there is something missing or wrong in the event parameters, but I can't figure out how to see anything about the custom event's definition.

I assume this is user error on my part, but I cannot find any helpful information, which is why I have turned to this community.

**What I have tried so far:**
I followed instructions for modifying an event, based on [this GA4 doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12844695?hl=en). I got the impression that I should be able to see how the event is defined so that I could alter it. How I interpreted the instructions is that I should be able to click on an existing event to modify it. But when I follow those instructions, I get the following screen that makes it appear as if there are no existing custom events, but that is clearly not the case as demonstrated in the other screenshot.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how modifying a custom event should behave? If so, what means is there for viewing how an existing custom event has been defined when it was first created?

Comment: You need to figure out if your website/application is leveraging Google Tag manager for your event based tracking or pushing those events manually. You can inspect the page and see what is in the code. That will give you a hint as to how they are getting to GA4.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is a mix of events that are defined in GTM and some in GA4. It's the ones that are defined in GA4 that I really want to see how they were defined. I can see the GTM event definitions easily enough.

Comment: Do you have admin/owner rights?

Comment: Yes, I do. I think something in our setup is broken. If not that - is it possible that these other events were defined by devs in the data layer and that is why we can't see the definition? I may be grasping at straws here due to ignorance. :)